# Wildcard query only returns results if query is exactly "*"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.7.0, and I'm trying to make a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), say to select documents where the field `datafile_url` ends with `.RLF`.

To start with a simple query, I just use the wildcard `*` to query for *any* value:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
     "wildcard": {
        "datafile_url": "*"
     }
  }
}
```

This returns documents, such as this one:

```
{
  "_index" : "data",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "1HzJaWoBVj7X61Ih767N",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "datafile_url" : "/uploads/data/1/MSN001.RLF",
    ...
  }
},
```

Ok, great. But when I change the wildcard query to `*.RLF`, I get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** That is because elastic applies [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) when the default analyzer is not explicitly specified for a field.

If you do a wild card search on the keyword, it will work and return expected result:

```
GET data/_search
{
  "query": {
     "wildcard": {
        "datafile_url.keyword": "*.RLF"
     }
  }
}
```

Now, for **some background** on why it doesnt work without `.keyword`

Take a look at this example and try running it on your own index.

```
POST data/_analyze
{
  "field": "datafile_url",
  "text" : "/uploads/data/1/MSN001.RLF"
}

#Result

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "uploads",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "data",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "1",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "msn001",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "rlf",
      "start_offset": 23,
      "end_offset": 26,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice how all special characters are missing in the inverted index. Your wild card search will only work on any of the above words from the inverted index. for example:

```
#this will work
    GET data/_search
    {
      "query": {
         "wildcard": {
            "datafile_url": "*rlf"
         }
      }
    }

#this will NOT work because of case sensitive inverted index.
    GET data/_search
    {
      "query": {
         "wildcard": {
            "datafile_url": "*RLF"
         }
      }
    }
```

You would need to write a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) if you wan to preserve those special characters.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds like I really just wanted my field to be a Keyword field in the first place.